# how to get ajax response change the html content in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am using my ajax form like this

```
<%= form_tag :url => { :action => 'run' },:id => "tool-form",:remote =>true,:update => { :success => "response", :failure => "error" },:loading => "$('#loading').toggle()", :complete => "alert(123)"  do %>
                    <% submit_tag "mona"%>
                <% end %>
```

how can i use the data recieved as response and set to some html element after the ajax call is complete

Comment: Is there any reason that you are running the JavaScript from your view?  Is this in an html.erb or a js.erb?

Comment: well i wasnt really aware of this yet , so i used script in my view page , but  now  i know that script should be inside the js.erb file ,

Answer (score 0):

In your view folder, create a partial named `_run.js.erb` and put the js you'd like to be applied on the page on the success.

In your controller :

```
def run
  @data = "important data"

  render :partial => 'run'
end
```

In views/{controller}/_run.js.erb, where {controller} is the name of your controller

```
alert("<%= @data %>");
```

Comment: followed what you said , nothing happens